# Jquery checkbox affect one item not all items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I was wondering if someone can help me please, I have a series of checkboxes that when clicked change the div background, activate 2 inputs and add a tick icon. My issue is that when one check box is checked the class .TickIco shows for all and so does the .disableToggle

How can i get it so that this only affects one .checkBG at a time and not all of them?

Hopefully this JSFiddle will help explain what I mean.

https://jsfiddle.net/jayjay89/xfg96we5/

thanks

```
$(".checkBG").click(function () {
var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
var location = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
if (checked) {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().addClass("activeformBlock");
    $(".tickIco").show();
    $(".disabletoggle").removeAttr("disabled");


} else {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().removeClass("activeformBlock");
    $(".tickIco").hide();
    $(".disabletoggle").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

});

thanks

Comment: how are we supposed to know which items need to be shown without any markup? post the html....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the context in which the selector will be looked.

You already have the location variable which is the parent context for one of your row

```
$(".checkBG").click(function () {
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
    var location = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
    if (checked) {
        $(this,location).parent().parent().parent().addClass("activeformBlock");
        $(".tickIco",location).show();
        $(".disabletoggle",location).removeAttr("disabled");


    } else {
        $(this,location).parent().parent().parent().removeClass("activeformBlock");
        $(".tickIco",location).hide();
        $(".disabletoggle",location).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you!! That is what I was trying to work out but I kept putting it in the wrong place. Thanks so much!!!

Comment: you are welcome :) . Yes, After looking your code i was able to identify that you are thinking in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue lies in the way you are selecting the `.tickIco` and `.disabletoggle` elements:

```
$(".tickIco").show();
$(".disabletoggle").removeAttr("disabled");
```

These jquery calls use selectors that match **all** classes of `.tickIco` and `.disabletoggle`.

---

Dirty solution (finds elements of the parent with matching classes using [**`.find()`**](https://jsfiddle.net/jayjay89/xfg96we5/#fork)):

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".tickIco").show();
$(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.disabletoggle').removeAttr("disabled")
```

---

Better solution:

jQuery selecter takes the context of your selection as a second argument so you can:

```
var context = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
$(".tickIco", context).show();
$('.disabletoggle', context).removeAttr("disabled")
```